# How to write multiple lines of code inside a JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I want to be able to write multiple lines of code inside a promise. Here's the code https://jsfiddle.net/j3210938120/bqhfyL0k/12/

```
var callCount = 0;

var chartdata = [];

function ajaxCallFun() {

  return $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify({callCount: ++callCount})
    },
    //dataType: 'json',
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data, data.length)
    chartdata.push(data.callCount);
  })

}

setInterval(function(){
    ajaxCallFun().done((data) => function(){
    for (i=0;i<chartdata.length;i+=1){
      console.log(i);
    }
    //do a bunch of other stuff here
    //and then empty array
    chartdata = [];
  });
}, 1000);
```

I'm not sure about the right syntax to get this done in lines 22 to 29.

Comment: Remove `(data) =>`. That's making your `done()` callback return a function that is never executed. In general, don't mix arrow and regular functions unless you know exactly when to use each (usually around how you want to use `this`)

Comment: *or* remove `function(){` as in:  `.done((data) => {`  https://jsfiddle.net/pmj6o5nb/